# Java Exception in R Shiny Reactive Runtime

Tags: r, jdbc, shiny

I am having issues with an interaction between shiny and JDBC.

One should be able to reproduce the error using the following snippet (system info follows).

The things I have found are:

- This bug doesn't seem to exist using openjdk-8, but it begins in openjdk-11 and effects all higher versions that I have tested.
- The problem seems to be querying SQL from within a `reactive`. Calls outside the reactive are successful.
- I have attempted to instantiate the connection in the global environment, within the server, and within the reactive itself. None of these approaches solve the problem.
- When I examine the connection object, a call to `conn@jc` yields a string like `"Java-Object{net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsConnection@13fee20c}"`. Within the reactive, this becomes: `"Java-Object{}"`. In particular, the print method for the java object includes`rJava::.jstrVal(conn@jc)` which appears to throw the error as well when accessed via `rJava::.jcheck()` (again, only within the reactive).
- Upon quitting the app runtime, the same connection becomes functional again.

I wonder if the issue has something to do with some multi-threading magic on the shiny backend. A pointer being misplaced? When I look at my `jobj`outside of the reactive, I see  `<pointer: 0x556992f51450>`, however when the error throws, I see this:

```r
Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>`<reactive:one>`(...)new("jobjRef", jobj = <pointer: 0x556992f51448>, jclass = "java/lang/Throwable")
```

I'm not sure if those pointers should match or not. They almost do!

Anyway, I'm hopeful someone with more expertise in shiny particularly can help me with this.

```r
library(shiny)

## We are using JTDS, but this problem does not seem to be driver specific, as I
## tested on Microsoft's JDBC driver (version 12) as well.
drvr <- RJDBC::JDBC(
  driverClass = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver",
  classPath = Sys.getenv("classPath"))

## Set these environment variables to your username, password, and a connection
## string.
conn <- RJDBC::dbConnect(
  drv = drvr,
  user = Sys.getenv("user"),
  password = Sys.getenv("password"),
  Sys.getenv("connectionString"))

## A simple UI.
ui <- bootstrapPage(plotOutput("plot"))

server <- function(input, output){

  ## This call works.
  x <- RJDBC::dbGetQuery(
    conn = conn,
    statement = "select * from sys.tables")

  one <- reactive({

    ## This call throws an error like the following:
    ##   Warning: Error in .jcheck: Java Exception <no description because
    ##   toString() failed>.jcall(conn@jc, "Z", "getAutoCommit")
    ##   new("jobjRef", jobj = <pointer: 0x564bbbc301d0>, jclass =
    ##   "java/lang/Throwable")
    Y <- RJDBC::dbGetQuery(
      conn = conn,
      statement = "select * from sys.tables")
    return(1)
  })

  ## Some dummy output.
  output$plot <- renderPlot(plot(one()))
}

## Run the application.
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

And my session info:

```r
 R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15)
 Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
 Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)

 Matrix products: default
 BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
 LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

 locale:
  [1] LC_CTYPE=C.UTF-8          LC_NUMERIC=C
  [3] LC_TIME=C.UTF-8           LC_COLLATE=C.UTF-8
  [5] LC_MONETARY=C.UTF-8       LC_MESSAGES=C.UTF-8
  [7] LC_PAPER=C.UTF-8          LC_NAME=C.UTF-8
  [9] LC_ADDRESS=C.UTF-8        LC_TELEPHONE=C.UTF-8
 [11] LC_MEASUREMENT=C.UTF-8    LC_IDENTIFICATION=C.UTF-8

 attached base packages:
 [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

 other attached packages:
 [1] shiny_1.7.4

 loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
  [1] Rcpp_1.0.9       crayon_1.5.2     digest_0.6.30    later_1.3.0
  [5] mime_0.12        R6_2.5.1         DBI_1.1.3        jsonlite_1.8.3
  [9] lifecycle_1.0.3  xtable_1.8-4     magrittr_2.0.3   RJDBC_0.2-10
 [13] cachem_1.0.6     rlang_1.1.0      cli_3.4.1        promises_1.2.0.1
 [17] jquerylib_0.1.4  bslib_0.4.2      ellipsis_0.3.2   tools_4.0.4
 [21] httpuv_1.6.6     fastmap_1.1.0    compiler_4.0.4   memoise_2.0.1
 [25] rJava_1.0-8      htmltools_0.5.4  sass_0.4.2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved this inadvertently this afternoon.

By toying with random java options, I ran across `-Xss`, and tried:

```r
options(java.parameters = "-Xss256m")
```

And now everything works.

I am still not clear on what is happening here, as the output of `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` produces 1024 for `ThreadStackSize` on both the Java 8 machine (where the `R` code works), and the Java 11 machine (where it does not work without the `-Xss` overwrite.

Maybe someone more knowledgeable can give some color here - but I cannot!

Comment: This works! But I still don't get it why the rJava in Reactive needs a bigger "max stack size" (256m seems to be much larger than default values).

Comment: Where to put this?

Comment: @Festlandtommy this is just a call to `options`, so it could go anywhere. In this case, since it's setting options for the instantiation of the JVM, you will have to call it in a fresh `R` session prior to running anything from `rJava`.